# Replace date placeholders with default variables

Tags: php

I'm able to change the date to the desired output by editing ('fourth', 'Fri', 'Jun', 2019) but I don't want to have to do that. How do I replace the strings so the second and fourth date are automatically calculated? I've tried getting the current date and importing that variable, but can't get it to work. cut off date: the cut off date is set as the coming bimonthly Friday (eg cut off dates are Jun 14 and Jun 28. if the submission is done today, then cut off date is Jun 28. if the submission is done on Jun 30, the cut off date would be Jul 12) Help pls thanks.

**Current result:** 06-28-2019

**Expected result:** The second and fourth friday of the month for current date. Currently I have to keep changing the date string in the code to get whatever output I want. It should automatically get the current date and display the second and fourth friday of the month for whatever the date is.

```
class MyDateTime extends DateTime
{
    /**
     * Returns a MyDateTime object set to 00:00 hours on the nth occurence
     * of a given day of the month
     *
     * @param string $n nth day required, eg first, second etc
     * @param string $day Name of day
     * @param mixed $month Month number or name optional defaults to current month
     * @param mixed $year optional defaults to current year
     *
     * @return MyDateTime set to last day of month
     */
    public function nthDayOfMonth($n, $day, $month = null, $year = null)
    {
        $timestr = "$n $day";
        if(!$month) $month = $this->format('M');
        $timestr .= " of $month $year";
        $this->setTimestamp(strtotime($timestr));
        $this->setTime(0, 0, 0);
        return $this;
    }
}
$dateTime = new MyDateTime();
echo $dateTime->nthDayOfMonth('fourth', 'Fri', 'Jun', 2019)->format('m-d-Y');
?>
```

It will be stored/displayed in a html form input field like this

```
<input type="text" name="cutoffdate" id="cutoffdate" value=" 
<?php echo $datetime; ?>" readonly>
```

Comment: Could you please add some example input and the expected result? You should also add what result you're currently getting.

Comment: Yes please, like @MagnusEriksson said. Otherwise I/we cannot understand what you are asking

Comment: Looks right to me https://3v4l.org/8UmZQ What do you mean second and forth dates?

Comment: @AbraCadaver Yea whats here works but OP wants 2 of the parameters to default or something ( I think )

Comment: Updated. Let me know if it's still not clear

Comment: Its still not clear. What has that HTML and `contact_number` got to do with a **Date** calulated by your `MyDateTime` class

Comment: pls help lol I update again thats where I'll be displaying the datetime which is the cutoffdate

Comment: Things will have to change quite a bit as this method only returns ONE date and now you want 2 dates returned and you cannot `->format()` if it returns 2 dates!

Comment: Yes, but if I can get one working I know I can figure out the other. I need to know how to make it where I dont have to go in my code and change date everytime there is a new cut off date. I updated more it should be clear.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it for you by simply hard coding the second and fourth part and using the `date()` function to get current month and year

```
<?php
class MyDateTime extends DateTime
{
    /**
     * Returns a MyDateTime object set to 00:00 hours on the nth occurence
     * of a given day of the month
     *
     * @param string $n nth day required, eg first, second etc
     * @param string $day Name of day
     * @param mixed $month Month number or name optional defaults to current month
     * @param mixed $year optional defaults to current year
     *
     * @return MyDateTime set to last day of month
     */
    public function nthDayOfMonth($n, $day, $month = null, $year = null)
    {
        $timestr = "$n $day";
        if(!$month) $month = $this->format('M');
        $timestr .= " of $month $year";
        $this->setTimestamp(strtotime($timestr));
        $this->setTime(0, 0, 0);
        return $this;
    }

    public function secondFriday()
    {
        $timestr = 'second friday of ' . date('M') . ' ' . date('Y');
        $this->setTimestamp(strtotime($timestr));
        $this->setTime(0, 0, 0);
        return $this;
    }

    public function fourthFriday()
    {
        $timestr = 'fourth friday of ' . date('M') . ' ' . date('Y');
        $this->setTimestamp(strtotime($timestr));
        $this->setTime(0, 0, 0);
        return $this;       
    }
}
$dateTime = new MyDateTime();
echo $dateTime->secondFriday()->format('m-d-Y') . ' / ' . $dateTime->fourthFriday()->format('m-d-Y') ;
```

Comment: you're my hero. Thank you.

Comment: @AmateurCodeHayden - If this answer solved your issue, you should accept it.